# if |x -4 | + |y - 4| =4 then how many integers value is possible for the set (x,y)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I did it like this,

|x-4|=(x-4) or -(x-4) 
since absolute value of x can have 2 values +x and -x.
Thus,
(x-4)+(y-4)=4
or x+y=12 
(4-x)+(4-y)=4
or x+y=4
thus i got,
(11,1),
(11,1),
(10,2),
(2,10),
(9,3),
(3,9),
(8,4),
(4,8),
(7,5),
(5,7),
(6,6),
(0,12),
(12,0)
(1,3),
(3,1),
(0,4),
(4,0),
(2,2).
Thus i got 18 solutions.
But the answer is 16.
Is my process wrong?
If so then why am I wrong???

Comment: $(3,9)$ and $(9,3)$ are not the solutions.

Comment: (0,12) and (12,0) are not solutions

Comment: Well for one $|11-4|=7$ so $(11,1)$ is definitely wrong

Comment: You have confused yourself with the definition and the concept of absolute value.

Comment: Note that the answer is the same for $|x|+|y|=4$, and you are I think far more likely to count this right.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the symmetry of the problem, the solutions can be interchanged for x and y. Now $|x -4|$ can take values from $0$ to $4$ which means x can take values from $0$ to $8$ (9 values) so there will be $18$ solutions unless $x=y$. So we count out 2 of them (2,2) and (6,6). So in all there are $\color{blue}{16}$ solutions, without enlisting them.

Comment: Brilliant. Short, simple and sweet.

Comment: Are you Shailesh Shirali? I have a strong suspicion.

Comment: Anyway , thanks. I was browsing through your answers and they are all of very high quality. And you don't ask question, you only answer.

Comment: Sure , I will keep in mind. I think in  near future I need your help. I will surely send you pm.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=|x-4|$ and $b=|y-4|$, then  $a , b \in N $ and we have $a +b =4$ . So $ b=4-a $. Thus the possible values of  $a$ and  $b$  are :

for $a=0$ --> $b=4$. Thus $|x-4|=0$ and $|y-4|=4$, which implies $x=4$ and  $y-4=4 $ or $y-4=-4$ . So here we have 2 solutins  $(4,8)$ and $(4,0 )$.

for $a=1$ --> $b=3$. Thus $|x-4|=1$ and $|y-4|=3$ . So here we have 4 solutins  $(5,7)$ , $(5,1 )$,  $(3,7)$ and $(3,1 )$.

for $a=2$ --> $b=2$. Thus $|x-4|=2$ and $|y-4|=2$ . So here we have 4 solutins  $(2,2)$ , $(2,6 )$,  $(6,2)$ and $(6,6 )$.

for $a=3$ --> $b=1$. Thus $|x-4|=3$ and $|y-4|=1$ . So here we have 4 solutins  $(7,5)$ , $(7,3 )$,  $(1,5)$ and $(1,3 )$.

for $a=4$ --> $b=0$. Thus $|x-4|=4$ and $|y-4|=0$ . So here we have 2 solutins  $(8,4)$ and $(0,4 )$.

Thus, we have  16 solutions .